# To add and subtract digits in a number

Tags: mips32

I am trying to add the first 3 digits and last 3 digits of the series of numbers and subtracting the second result with the first. I will have to use the `load byte` and `store byte` commands. But when I use `sb`, I get the wrong answer.

My code is as follows (in MIPS assembly language):

```
.data
D1: .byte 1,7,2,0,0,3
D2: .byte 0
.text
.globl main
main: la $t0,D1
la $t9,D2
lb $t1,0($t0)
lb $t2,4($t0)
add $t3,$t1,$t2
lb $t4,8($t0)
add $t3,$t3,$t4
lb $t5,16($t0)
lb $t6,20($t0)
lb $t7,24($t0)
add $t8,$t5,$t6
add $t8,$t8,$t7
sub $t8,$t8,$t3
sb $t8,0($t9)
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Until `sub $t8,$t8,$t3` I get the correct answer `-7` that is stored in `$t8` but when I use sb, the answer is `249`. I am unable to figure out why that is.

Answer (score 0):

The number -7(signed) in binary is :

11111111 11111111 11111111 11111001

And number 249(signed) is :

00000000 00000000 00000000 11111001

sb (save byte) , saves just one byte(8LS bits). This is why you'r getting 249 instead of -7.

After sb you can do :

`lui $t8, 65535` # this will change the first 16 bits from 0 to 1
then add the correct number to `$t8` to take the wished output.

However i do not know what you're trying to accomplish.